# 500 error when WebClient.DownloadString()

Tags: c#, httprequest, html-parsing, webclient

I am trying to parse html for catch bet rates for all matches from this [site](https://www.87tempobet.com/) with c#.

I am using this code for catch match rates on another website and its working well.

```
Uri url = new Uri("https://1xbetm.mobi/LineFeed/Get1x2_VZip?sports=1&count=500&lng=tr&tf=1500000&tz=3&mode=4&country=190&getEmpty=true");
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string jsonOneXBetData = client.DownloadString(url);
```

But when I change the Url as

```
Uri url = new Uri("https://www.87tempobet.com");
```

I am getting 500 error :(

I was try to read this website request actions with [Fiddler 4](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) but I cant find correct Url.

I was try to use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html). But I dont know how can i filter local reuqests and see the urls..

So I dont know what I need to do.. Can you you please help me ?

Comment: 500 error is server side. They are probably detecting that your user agent isn't a real one and 'blocking' you.

Comment: But how can they detect my request ? What is the different between web browser 
 request and programmatically request ? I dont know the logic, Maybe I should send request validation token  but I already dont know how can I read and send.

Comment: I'd suggest you have a read up on Selenium.

Comment: And I need to ask something too. First time when I was try to read data from [bets10](https://www.213bets10.com/tr/) I was saw same error. 500 error. But I was look at the network and I found an `Api` which this site using for get matches and rates as `JSON` .. But I cant find any data source for this site :(

Comment: You must send a request from web and capture that request in fiddler or wireshark. And then look into the request headers. Then, you must send those request headers in your web client request from C# code. Usually, when we send request from webclient there is no referrer and user-agent request header due to which most of the sites deny request.

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal thank you for your answer. I can read the request header but I dont know how can I send this header with `WebClient` Request. Can you please give me some advice or some link for teach me to how can I do this ?

Comment: Give me a few minutes. I'll share piece of code with you.

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal thank you. I am waiting for your help.

Comment: This way you'll be able to add request headers.
`WebClient wc = new WebClient();
   wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko");`

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal I will try it . If this will work I will come back and up your answers! Really thank you !

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal unfortunately its not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to decorate your request headers as following:

```
Uri url = new Uri("https://1xbetm.mobi/LineFeed/Get1x2_VZip?sports=1&count=500&lng=tr&tf=1500000&tz=3&mode=4&country=190&getEmpty=true");
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko");

string jsonOneXBetData = client.DownloadString(url);
```

**Edit 1:**
For the other url it seems to be needed 2 more header parameters:

```
Uri url = new Uri("https://www.86tempobet.com?reloadlive=240671122&no_write_sess=1");
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko");
client.Headers.Add("method","POST");
client.Headers.Add("cookie","{cookie}");

string jsonOneXBetData = client.DownloadString(url);
```

**Edit 2:**
Here is the complete request to access the response as json :)

```
Uri url = new Uri("https://www.86tempobet.com?reloadlive=240671122&no_write_sess=1");
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36");
client.Headers.Add("method","POST");
client.Headers.Add("cookie","visid_incap_1875943=C4HkVjo8RCCFldh593iChSbq6VsAAAAAQUIPAAAAAABzSYMXxV4TSKKZijRL24QX; incap_ses_277_1875943=ZnjKE7twmRYrT7s2YxvYAybq6VsAAAAAFdaEfL/KiNMUMywbnQeCNA==; GAMBLINGSESS=jfr3uadgl1ogv55c06ee6mvvs3fiv86p; nlbi_1875943=4NdhZ5rR80YChdm11QdqAQAAAAA3PlRp/yXvrsgK9rbvAEPs; _ga=GA1.2.449421393.1542056499; _gid=GA1.2.2110672116.1542056499; docscrollltop=0; LPVID=FkMTc4MDEwMzY3NDllNjU5; LPSID-34568906=eQOy1bjvTWS3lx1mTF5b3w");
client.Headers.Add("x-requested-with","XMLHttpRequest");
client.Headers.Add("betslip-hash","578c9b9896d955c14a698bf17937400a");
client.Headers.Add("content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
client.Headers.Add("ajax-json","true");

string jsonOneXBetData = client.DownloadString(url);
```

Comment: this url was an example. Its so easy to get rates from 1xbet. I need to get rates from [**86tempobet**](http://86tempobet.com)  I didnt try your way now because its my home project and I am at work right now (as you :)). But thank you for your help . I will try it. İyi çalışmalar hocam :) Have a nice day

Comment: Ok, for youe specifik request it seems to be needed 2 more header parameters, which is "cookie" and "method". My request worked when I switched to:
See the edited code example :) Bol sanslar, ve sanada iyi calismalar usta!

Comment: I did tried but it didnt work :( Can I ask you something ? How did you found this `Url` `reloadlive=240671122&no_write_sess=1`

Comment: Did you replaced the cookie value with a local one you recieved from the site? The source site uses client script for to update the scores, I just used my browser (Chrome) developer mode and checked the Network tab.

Comment: Yes, I was changed it. But it didnt work :( Did your code worked when you try it first time ?

Comment: Just check my lastest edit, it has all missing header paramaters and the response is exactly the same as for my browser. good luck :)

Comment: Yeah it worked fine at my first request, I recommend you to find this specifik call from your browser and find out the session id and cookie with those you have recieved from the site

Comment: You need to replace following parameters with yours: "reloadlive", "cookie", "betslip-hash"

Comment: Are you working with chrome or firefox? Because I cant find reloadlive and betslip-hash in my chrome  :(

Comment: I am using chrome but firefox works fine too, if you switch to Network tab you will see those with http method "POST", select one of those requests and switch to form parameters, that tab will have "reloadlive".

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I was found all of parameters. betslip-hash is same for us . But there is another problem now. "reloadlive" changing every 10 /30 seconds. I think its because keepalive. I still didnt get any data from this website .

Comment: No problem! Tried to execute without "reloadlive" and it still seems to work. Your cookie might be expired, visit the site and copy a newer cookie value. Since the site seems refresh data and some key parameters with client scripts it can be a hell to manage what you are trying to do, but it is still possible. I think the solution I have presented will help to scrap the data as you want to but you need to somehow solve the issues with client script behavior and simulate a similar  behavior

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183551/discussion-between-hamit-gundogdu-and-mustafa-alan).

Comment: I am waiting you in chat . I hope you will  come @Hamit